# Ora-39000 bad dump file specification when exporting dump file using expdp

Tags: oracle, batch-file, database-backups, expdp

I am trying to perform a windows scheduler job  which will create back up of my database daily once. So for this reason I have created batch file `SYSTEM_BACKUP.bat` which contains data:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
expdp SYSTEM/SYSTEM@XE PARFILE=export_dump.par
```

The export_dump.par file contains information:

```
DIRECTORY=cron_jobs
DUMPFILE=SYSTEM_!date:~10,4!!date:~6,2!.!date:~4,2!.dmp
LOGFILE=SYSTEM.log
SCHEMAS=B1,B2
CONTENT=ALL
```

When i trying to run the `SYSTEM_BACKUP.bat` I am getting error as

```
  ORA-39001:invalid argument value,
  ORA-39000 bad dump file specification,
  ORA-39087:directory name ratormonitor_!date is invalid.
```

I am trying to create dump file with current datetimestamp attached to the file so the dump file name should look like this `SYSTEM_2015.02.03.37.029062831 but getting an error.`

Comment: @jeb i have edited my question now

Comment: It's still a duplicate, but the errors are: You need to add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in your batch, then `!` expansion works. And the slash `/` in `!date:~6,2!/!date:~4,2!.dmp` should be probably a `.`

Comment: @jeb i have edited my question now with you suggestion but still getting same error. I am very new to this concept. I have check your previous quetion but did not get any help from that question and still my problem has not been solved thats why i have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your export_dump.par file contains

```
DUMPFILE=I_!date:~10,4!!date:~6,2!.!date:~4,2!.dmp
```

But as this isn't part of a batch file, the process expdp.exe which reads the file doesn't know anything about delayed expansion or variable expansion at all.

So you have to create this file by your batch file each time before you start expdp

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    echo DIRECTORY=cron_jobs
    echo DUMPFILE=I_!date:~10,4!!date:~6,2!.!date:~4,2!.dmp
    ...
) > export_dump.par
expdp SYSTEM/SYSTEM@XE PARFILE=export_dump.par
```

Comment: Then you should look how your date variable is formatted, as the format is localized. There are enough questions about exactly this at SO

Comment: ohh ok i will look into this